# Change Network Interface Without Authentication PopUp in MAC Application

Tags: objective-c, macos, networking, authorization, system-configuration

I am working on MAC Application in which I have to create a VPN Connection through my application and which I have done successfully with the Help of **EBAS** Example code from Apple.

**Now when user want to connect to VPN, I need to modify the Network Interface and for that an AUTHORIZATION POPUP Comes to get user Permission.**

This is the Process to Modify the Network Interface.

First Lock the System Preference using Below Code

```
Boolean result = SCPreferencesLock(prefToUnlock,TRUE); // Authentication PopUp Comes here to lock the system preferences.
```

and then rest of the code to modify the network which is working fine.

**Now whenever above line execute popup comes to get authorization to Lock SystemPeference. I want this to be done by Helper Tool Without Authorization Popup. I tried that but it always returns false.**

Is there any other way I can archive this.

Thanks

Comment: Hey @Malav were you able to find a solution?

Comment: yes you can run above line of code in your custom helper tool function and call that function from your from-end application. It works for me... Hope it works for you too

Comment: I found the issue I was having thanks! Are you able to modify the connection entry for example change the server address?

Comment: No it was not possible so i delete the previous entry and create new entry in network.

Comment: I planned to do that, but wont that lose the service order that the user might set?